# DateTime.Parse date conversion is not consistent

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel sheet where one column has a date. I have C# code to take that column, convert it to a date and then insert it to a SQL database.

The conversion is done like this:

```
r.transactionDate = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value));
```

The data transfer is working without an issue.

When the date in the Excel sheet is something like 25/05/2022 (25th of May), it is converted properly and the date I get in the SQL database is the 25/05/2022.

However, the problem is when the date is something like 12/05/2022 (12th May); it is converted to 05/12/2022 (05th of December).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you converting something to a `string` and then parsing it to a `DateTime`? What is it actually in the first place?

Comment: Regardless of anything else, if you want parse a `string` to a `DateTime` in a specific format, you should be calling `ParseExact` and specifying that format rather than calling `Parse`.

Comment: Excel sometimes uses the US date format unless expressly forced to do something else, regardless of your regional settings. CSV import is one of the more annoying times this happens. Since '12/05/2022' is a valid date in both US and more sane formats, the value is handled inconsistently. What type is the actual value? Does it look correct when you load the workbook in Excel?

Comment: What are you using to access the Excel sheet? COM automation? A library like EPPlus?

Comment: @jmcilhinney It's an excel sheet downloaded from Paypal that has all the dates of payments.  There is a date column with dates. If I don't convert that to string first, it throws an error. Therefore I converted it to string first.

Comment: What error? `DateTime.Parse` requires a `string` so I don't think that your code would compile even if the data was text, because `Value` would return an `object` reference or the like. If it's text then you should be casting, not converting. If it's not text then what is it? There's probably a better way to get a `DateTime` than converting to a `string` and parsing that.

Comment: If the value from excel is just a number without separators like `/` or `-` then it is probably the OADate format. Try `DateTime.FromOADate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's an excel sheet downloaded from Paypal that has all the dates of payments. There is a date column with dates.

Paypal does not offer a download in XLS or XLSX format. What you have is, most likely, a CSV file that Excel can open. It appears as an Excel file in your file system because Excel has registered the CSV file extension.

CSV (Comma-Separated Values) is a text file with all values represented as strings, separated by the `,` character. It has been around for a very long time, but was never formally specified. Or more precisely, formal specifications for CSV have been created several times, and nobody really knows which one is the right one. CSV files that work perfectly with one program can be unreadable to another.

Excel's CSV import is notorious for using US date formats regardless of your computer's regional settings. Each value is separated and examined individually. If the value looks like a date format then Excel attempts to parse it as a US date. If the first set of digits is in the range 1-12 then it is interpreted as the month. If the first set of digits is 13 or more then it tries the regional date strings, and may fall back to day-first if that fails. (This varies apparently.)

For this reason (among others) I strongly recommend that you never open a CSV file via Excel automation. Ever. In fact you should never open a CSV file with dates in it using Excel unless you know that the file was generated with month-first date formats only. Even then it is a needless waste of resources to open a text file with Excel.

You can do better.

There are plenty of libraries out there that will help you with CSV import. I've used a few ([`CsvHelper`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a reasonable starting place), but usually I just write something simple to do the job. Read the file a line at a time (`StreamReader.ReadLine`), split each line into a collection of values (via my `SplitCSV` method), then write a `ParseCSV` method for the type that takes a collection of strings and returns a configured object. That way I have direct control over the way the input data is interpreted without having Excel mess things up for me.

Here's a simple example:

```
const string InputFile = @"C:\Temp\test.csv";

static void Main()
{
    var rows = ReadCSV(InputFile, RowData.ParseCSV);
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"#{row.RowNum}, Date: {row.SomeDate}, Amount: ${row.Amount:#,0.00}");
    }
}

class RowData
{
    public int RowNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    
    public static RowData ParseCSV(string[] values)
    {
        if (values is null || values.Length < 3)
            return null;
        
        if (!int.TryParse(values[0], out var rownum) || 
            !DateTime.TryParse(values[1], out var somedate) ||
            !decimal.TryParse(values[2], out var amount)
        )
            return null;
        
        return new RowData 
        { 
            RowNum = rownum, 
            SomeDate = somedate, 
            Amount = amount
        };
    }
}

static IEnumerable<T> ReadCSV<T>(string filename, Func<string[], T> parser, bool skipHeaders = true)
    where T : class
{
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var line in Lines(filename))
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            if (skipHeaders)
                continue;
        }
        
        T curr = null;
        try
        {
            var values = SplitCSV(line);
            curr = parser(values);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do something here if you care about bad data.
        }
        
        if (curr != null)
            yield return curr;
    }
}

static string[] SplitCSV(string line)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    return internal_split().ToArray();
    
    // The actual split, done as an enumerator.
    IEnumerable<string> internal_split()
    {
        bool inQuote = false;
        foreach (char c in line)
        {
            if (c == ',' && !inQuote)
            {
                // yield value
                yield return sb.ToString();
                sb.Clear();
            }
            else if (c == '"')
                inQuote = !inQuote;
            else
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        // yield last field
        yield return sb.ToString();
    }
}

static IEnumerable<string> Lines(string filename)
{
    string line;
    using var reader = File.OpenText(filename);
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

(It's not the best way, but it's *a* way to do it.)

Comment: Thanks heaps Corey! I will implement this.

Comment: @GWP Glad I could help. Just be aware that the code above was typed in about 10 minutes from memory because my actual SplitCSV is about 150 lines right now - it handles a ton of different things, this barely handles quoted fields. It runs, but it needs a loooooot of work before you should use it in production :)